# How to clear form inside of dialog material angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a dialog created on angular 2 material. I'm opening the modal as follows:

**my component**

```
....
private refDialog;
@ViewChild('display') display;

openDialog() {
    this.refDialog= this.dialog.open(this.display);
}
....
```

**my html**

```
<ng-template #display>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
        <div class='col-md-12'>
            <md-input-container>
                <input mdInput placeholder="Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="product.name" #name="ngModel">
            </md-input-container>
        </div>

        .....

    </form>
</ng-template>
```

I need to clear the form before opening the dialog. I would like to do this as simply as possible. I was using the primeNG dialog and with it I used this.f.reset (); And it worked. But the angular material 2 work differently.

I tried everything without success. This does not work for me:

```
....
private refDialog;
@ViewChild('display') display;
@ViewChild('f') f;

openDialog() {
    this.f.reset();
    this.refDialog= this.dialog.open(this.display);
}

....
```

can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at the Plunker demo I created  : [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/HKz0pzpBEfrhXEBJBoPA?p=preview)

here is the dialog component:

```
export class DialogComponent implements OnInit{
  @ViewChild('myform') myform;
  constructor(public dialogRef: MdDialogRef<DialogComponent>){}
  ngOnInit() {
  this.myform.resetForm();
  }
}
```

here is the root component:

```
openDialog(){
  this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
}
```

as you can see in the GIF how the form gets cleared every time even the hard coded input values in the HTML gets cleared and the form dirty status so it gets a full rest using the `resetForm()` method
 [image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. this.f.restForm() not working. I checked that there is no instance of the form inside openDialog(). That's probably why he can not reset. I do not know how to get the form instance that is inside the angular material dialog. It seems to be a scope problem

Comment: I just created a plunker to replicate the issue and I will try to solve the problem and get back to you by updating this answer.

Comment: @DaniloSantos Check my updated answer now! if this helped you please make sure to select it as an answer :)